# How to increment a value in ngfor angular 6 for every third iteration

Tags: angular

**How to increment a value for every 3rd iteration in ngFor. 
 
 I want to achieve like this in angular ngfor, how to do this** 
I am using array of objects like below and I am looping tempArr[] using ngFor

```js
  tempArrA = ['item a', 'item b', 'item c', 'item d', 'item e', 'item f', 'item g', 'item h','item i', 'item j', 'item k', 'item l','item m', 'item n', 'item o', 'item p'];
  tempArrB = ['item f', 'item g', 'item h','item i', 'item j'];
  tempArrC = [ 'item j', 'item k', 'item l','item m', 'item n', 'item o', 'item p'];
  tempArr:any = [
    { 
      name: "one",
      items: this.tempArrA
      },
       { 
      name: "two",
      items: this.tempArrB
      },
       { 
      name: "three",
      items: this.tempArrC
      },
      ];
```

item a -- 1 
item b -- 1 
item c -- 1

item d -- 2 
item e -- 2 
item f -- 2

item g -- 3 
item h -- 3 
item i -- 3

and so on....

Comment: First idea: use [`ngFor` with an `index`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables).

Comment: I tried with an index but i dono how to increment for every 3 iteration. do you have any example snippet, which i can go through? @pzaenger

Comment: @SrinivasanKasiram but only for tempArrA ?

Comment: no I want for tempArr @Doflamingo19

Comment: do the same thing with for loop in a function to massage your data before using the ngFor.

Comment: can you give me an example code @AliAdravi

Comment: why not use some like  `<div *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index" [style.margin-bottom]="i && i%3==0?'1rem':null">...</div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this by using angular pipe.

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let data of tempArrA; let i = index">
  {{data | format : i}}
</div>
```

.pipe

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'format'
    })
    export class FormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
          let d = Math.floor(args / 3) + 1
          return value + d;
        }
    }
```

This pipe will take value as array value and an argument which will be index. In pipe a variable is initialized with value = 0. Than check `index%3 === 0` at this time increment that initialized value by 1 and return by concatinating
check working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snhcfv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: a stateful pipe is non standard. no clue how this behaves with multiple uses of the pipe

Comment: @bryan60 didn't get you can you please explain what you want to say. As i am also in learning phase in angular

Comment: the pipe you've written has a stateful parameter `i`. typically pipes are completely stateless. If you used that pipe again, I believe you would start where the last usage left off as I think pipes are singletons.  pipe transforms should be pure functions, same params give same output always, no reliance on state

Comment: you can fix this by instead doing `return Math.floor(value / 3) + 1` so there is no state reliance.  you could also name it `'stepper` and feed it a step argument like `| stepper : i : 3` and use the step argument instead of hard coding 3

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `array.reduce` to reduce your flat array into a 2-dimensional array.

**component.ts**

```
// simple array for this example
const source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

this.model = source.reduce((arr, current, idx) => {
  const index = Math.floor(idx / 3);
  if (arr.length === index) {
    arr.push([]);
  }

  arr[index].push(current);
  return arr;
}, []);
```

**component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of model; let i = index">
  <div *ngFor="let item of group">
    {{item}} -- {{i + 1}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

This simple example transforms an array of length 6

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Into a 2D array of length 2:

```
[
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 4, 5, 6 ]
]
```

Once you have your model in a structure that matches your needs, it becomes easy to use the outer index as your counter that increments by 3. You could even map the outer index to a new object if you need to do more with it.

It would be simple enough for you to convert this using your model.

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2hcrz

### How does this work?

I'm using the first 3 parameters of the `reduce` callback function here

```
(arr, current, idx)
```

And invoking `reduce` with an empty array - the second argument.

Think of `reduce` like `map` - it loops through the source array, and lets you put each value where you want.

In the callback:

- arr is the new array that gets built up and ultimately returned.
- current is the current value in the loop from the source array
- idx is the current index in the loop from the source array

Firstly I work out where in the new array we should add the current index by doing `Math.floor(idx / 3)`. This allows us to increment the target index by 1 every third increment of the source array. The rest is fairly simple javascript.

### With objects

It is trivial to use this with objects. The content doesn't matter here, it's the index in the original array that is driving the grouping:

```
    const source = [
      { name: 'One', id: 1 },
      { name: 'Two', id: 2 },
      { name: 'Three', id: 3 },
      { name: 'Four', id: 4 },
      { name: 'Five', id: 5 },
      { name: 'Six', id: 6 }
    ];

    this.objModel = source.reduce((arr, current, idx) => {
      const index = Math.floor(idx / 3);
      if (arr.length === index) {
        arr.push([]);
      }

      arr[index].push(current);
      return arr;
    }, []);
```

Comment: this could work but you haven't finished the answer. show it being used in a nested ngFor

Comment: Updated my example. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Typically in angular, you want to map your model data into a view friendly view-model, like so:

```
interface MyItemVm {
  value: string;
  viewIndex: number;
}

tempArrAVm: MyItemVm[] = tempArrA.map((value, idx) => ({value, viewIndex: Math.floor(idx / 3) + 1}))
```

then just loop it:

```
<div *ngFor="let itm of tempArrAVm">
  {{itm.value}} -- {{itm.viewIndex}}
</div>
```

this may be a bit heavy duty for your use case but it is the general solution to these sorts of problems. A modified version of the pipe solution posted before may work for your specific case.